# Dumping a database into a file from terminal freezes

Tags: mysql

I've had this a couple of times and I can't find a way around it. I'm dumping a mysql database from the terminal using the following command:

`mysql -uusername -p my_database > myfile.sql`

When I run that and enter my password I wait and wait but nothing happens, the file myfile.sql is created but has the size of 0k. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to dump a database?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` is for interacting with the database.

`mysqldump` is what you want for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Try (for linux)

```
    `mysqldump -u username -p my_database > /home/chandan/Desktop/myfile.sql`
```

Make sure you have `SELECT`,`SHOW VIEW`,`TRIGGER`,`LOCK TABLES` privileges to run mysqldump